# how to handle Ajax 401 (unauthorized access error) in Jquery datatables?

Tags: jquery, ajax, error-handling, datatable, server-side

I am using a datatable as follows:

```
    $('#resources_table').dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "columns": [
        { "data": "id" },
        { "data": "column1" },
        { "data": "column2" }
    ],
    "ajax": "/resource",
    "error": function(reason) {
        console.log("error encountered ! ");
        // process reason here to know the type of the error
        // and then take appropriate action
    }
});
```

Somehow I am not been able to catch error returned from the server. How to access `reason` and process `error` in serverside processing ajax based datatables?

PS: I am using the latest dataTable version: `DataTables 1.10.1`

Comment: Offhand, `"ajax": "/resource,` is missing a closing quote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it. Actually "ajax" takes one of the 3 types of values: either `string` or `object` or `function`.

One can use an object to specify corresponding options for ajax request as shown in a simple example below:

```
$('#resources_table').dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "columns": [
        { "data": "id" },
        { "data": "column1" },
        { "data": "column2" }
    ],
    "ajax": {
        "type": "GET",
        "url" :"/resources",
        // error callback to handle error
        "error": function(xhr, error, thrown) {
            console.log("Error occurred!");
            console.log(xhr, error, thrown);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue and wanted to keep the default DataTables error handling for all errors *except* 401 errors. I ended up using a mix of DataTables `statusCode` for status specific handlers and and override of `$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode` to get rid of the `alert` for errors I was specifically handling. I kept the alert for all other errors without specific handling:

```
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = function (settings, tn, msg) {
      if (settings && settings.jqXHR && settings.jqXHR.status == 401) {
          return; // Status code specific error handler will take care of this
      }
      alert(msg) // Alert for all other error types
    };
    $('#example').DataTable({
      "ajax": {
        "url": '/some/endpoint',
        "dataSrc": 0,
        "statusCode": {
          401: function (xhr, error, thrown) {
            window.location = window.location.origin + '/login/?next=' + window.location.pathname;
            return false
          }
        }
      },
    });
```